# random parameters negative binomial model in R

Tags: r

I did negative binomial model by using R by using the following code:

```
myModel <- glm.nb(V7 ~ V8 + V3 + V10 + V12 + V11 + V5, data = data)
summary(myModel)
```

V7 is the dependent variable. V8, V3, V10, V12, V11, and V5 are the independent variables. V8, V3, V10, and V12 are constant parameters. V11 and V5 are random parameters. Based on their basic characteristics, the parameters in the statistical models can work as fixed parameters or random parameters. Whether a parameter is random or fixed can be determined by the derived standard deviation for each parameter. In that case that the standard deviation of the parameter density is statistically significant under 95% confidence interval, the corresponding parameter is random. On the other hand if the standard deviation of the parameter is not statistically significant, the parameter is considered fixed across the population. The code is for negative binomial model. Is the code right? I need to get scale parameter for overdispersion and log Likelihood at convergence of RPNB model and log Likelihood with constant only.

I also want to calculate the marginal effect for random parameter negative binomial models by using the above variables such as V8, V3, V10, V12, V11, and V5. I tried to use the following code, but I got the error message.

```
myModel <- glm.nb(V7 ~ V8 + V3 + V10 + V12 + V11 + V5, data = data)
cplot(myModel, what = "effect")
```

Which code do I have to use to calculate elasticities for random parameter negative binomial models

I got the following R output by using the above code. How can I calculate or get t-statistics based on z value and df for random parameters negative binomial model?

```
Coefficients: Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
(Intercept) -4.470e-01 4.838e-01 -0.924 0.356
V8 2.377e-05 1.326e-05 1.793 0.073 . V3 1.963e-02 1.958e-02 1.002 0.316
V10 6.144e-03 4.671e-03 1.315 0.188
V12 -1.219e-03 5.726e-03 -0.213 0.831
V11 -6.452e-01 3.924e-01 -1.644 0.100

V5 2.528e-03 6.681e-03 0.378 0.705
Signif. codes: 0 ‘’ 0.001 ‘’ 0.01 ‘’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(0.6279) family taken to be 1)

Null deviance: 160.68  on 159  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 150.30 on 153 degrees of freedom (126 observations deleted due to missingness) AIC: 491.81
```

Comment: By random parameter you mean random effects? If that is so, you may not want to use glm.nb from MASS. you can try https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmTMB/vignettes/glmmTMB.pdf , you can set the zero inflation part to zero

Comment: Thank you so much for your comment. It is very helpful. I tried to use glmmTMB as follows and got the following error. Can you please let me know what I should do to fix this?

Comment: Family: nbinom2  ( log )
Formula:          V7 ~ V8 + V3 + V10 + V12 + V11 + V5
Data: data

     AIC      BIC   logLik deviance df.resid 
      NA       NA       NA       NA      278 


Overdispersion parameter for nbinom2 family (): 0.493 

Conditional model:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -7.046e-01  3.830e-01  -1.840 0.065805 .  
V8          -1.549e-06         NA      NA       NA    
V3           4.525e-02  1.238e-02   3.656 0.000256 ***
V10          3.050e-04  3.038e-03   0.100 0.920047

Comment: Hi @user13908, thanks for the update, it's a bit hard to read it from comments. I see it now in the question edit. You haven't clarify what is constant and random variable. what exactly do you mean?

Comment: Please see the above to see the error message.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Based on their basic characteristics, the parameters in the statistical models can work as fixed parameters or random parameters. Whether a parameter is random or fixed can be determined by the derived standard deviation for each parameter. In that case that the standard deviation of the parameter density is statistically significant under 95% confidence interval, the corresponding parameter is random. On the other hand if the standard deviation of the parameter is not statistically significant, the parameter is considered fixed across the population.

Comment: ok that sounds pretty confusing. you can check this link for what I meant by random or fixed effects https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/4700/what-is-the-difference-between-fixed-effect-random-effect-and-mixed-effect-mode

Comment: It sounds to me you are basically fitting a model and determining its significance. the glm.nb followed by summary or anova should work. I suggest you post your question on https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions , maybe someone else is aware of what is a "random parameter"